# I cannot install anything in terminal

Tags: dpkg

Someone was working with my desktop and now i cant install anything via terminal.

I used

```
apt-get install s.th
```

and it responds

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

im also using ubuntu 14.04 lts.

Comment: Open a terminal and run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'

Comment: and your 1st command is missing "sudo" too

Answer (score 2):

It says what to do in the respond, run `dpkg --configure -a`

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems within the command that you are trying to invoke:

### Permissions

First of all, you must be sure to have **root privileges** to install new packages with apt-get install.
For this reason you invoke the command with the **sudo** command:

```
sudo apt-get install s.th
```

You can find further detail on root and sudo command on the [Ubuntu official Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

### Do what pkgs ask you

May I suggest you to follow suggestions from dpkg? From the output you posted you can see that dpkg request to execute the command:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This will purge all the pending packages, and it will restore your system to a clean situation.

After that command I suggest to run even

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To force a system update.

### Apt-get regexp

From your command I can see that you are trying to setup the package **s.th**. Please that in consideration that **s.th** is interpreted by apt-get as a regular expression, and will setup all the packages that match that regexp.